# VSTS Release Management with an Azure Cloud Services project and environment variables

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-cloud-services, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Currently, I have a build definition that publishes as its artifact, an azure cloud services package. This is then deployed via release management. In my release pipeline, I then promote this package through various environments. What I don't understand is how to perform web.config transformations on deploy to an environment, as that happens during the build, and not during the deploy.

I can tokenize my web.config during the build, and then use a release task to replace those with the proper values per environment. If I were just publishing a website as my build artifact, then this would work just fine, but since my build artifact is an azure cspkg, then I don't have access to the config files.

Is there a way to have the release process create the azure cloud services package, instead of the build? This way I can do the token replacement before creating the package. I would like to stay away from having the release do a rebuild for every environment if possible. Ultimately, I'd like for a single artifact from the build to be promoted to each environment, only having it's configuration files changed along the way.

I've looked into maybe using CSPack? Right now the packages are built by a cloud services project (ccproj) using the visual studio build task with the '/t:Publish' option. If I were to use CSPack in the release process, what should the build artifact be, and would that mean not using the cloud services project at all?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have the release process create the azure cloud
>   services package, instead of the build?

You just need to move the task which create azure cloud services package from build definition to release definition.

Such as if you are using [Azure Cloud Service Deployment task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureCloudPowerShellDeploymentV1) in build definition, you can remove the task from build definition and add it in release definition.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. That part I understand. My question wasn't really about deploying, more about building and packaging. I think need to move the packing part into the release process as well and have the build publish the artifacts needed by cspack. Haven't gotten it working quite yet, though.

Comment: @Chipootle Can you show the build/release definition you are using? And what's the problem have you met after changing the build/release definition?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git, you can just add an artifact with **Git type** and specify corresponding git repository (no build artifact associated).

If you are using TFVC, you can just a **Publish Build Artifacts** task to publish source files of project/solution, then associate the build to release.

With both ways, you can add **Visual Studio Build task** to release definition to build project.